# Ramification: Riemann surfaces vs Number fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-surfaces, covering-spaces

I am trying to understand the connection between Riemann surfaces and number fields. I am wondering if there an inconsistency in the definition of ramification in terms of Riemann surfaces vs number fields?

Given a compact Riemann surface $X$ and a finite cover $$\pi : X \to \mathbb{P}^1$$ we get an induced map on the function fields, $$\pi ^* : \mathbb{C}(\mathbb{P}^1) \to \mathbb{C}(X)$$ this turns out to be an inclusion, so we get a finite field extension $$\mathbb{C}(X) / \mathbb{C}(\mathbb{P}^1)$$

We say a point $P \in X$ is ramified if locally, $\pi$ looks like $z\mapsto z^e$ for some $e>1$.

We say a prime ideal $(p)\subset\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{P}^1)$ ramifies if it has a factorisation in $\mathbb{C}(X)$, $(p)=\mathfrak{p}_1^{e_1}...\mathfrak{p}_r^{e_r}$, where any one of the $e_i$ is $>1$.

But $(p)$ corresponds to an element of $\mathbb{P}^1$, so to be consistent,  would it not make more sense to say $\mathfrak{p}_1^{e_1}$ ramifies, and that $(p)$ is a branch point?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I think the term "ramifies" is reserved for number fields (or perhaps for global fields), while the term "branches" is reserved for Riemann surfaces. In the end, these are just words and hence it makes little sense to argue about them.

Comment: GH: "Ramification" is certainly also used in the Riemann surface case as well, but I agree with your main point that these are just words.

Comment: Griffiths and Harris say that $e$ is the ramification index of the _map_ $\pi$ at $P$; if $e>1$, then $P$ is a branch point. I don't think you would say that $(p)$ is a branch point, because geometrically the branches occur only at the ramified points lying above $(p)$, and some points above $(p)$ may be unramified. To me, "$(p)$ ramifies" is what happens to $(p)$ when you map it to the corresponding ideal in the extension; Griffiths and Harris don't use this terminology with Riemann surfaces.